# Certain websites not rendering correctly in Firefox/Chrome/Chromium

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, browser

Some elements on webpages are not rendering correctly in Ubuntu 18.04. These mostly include things like icon links and scrollable lists among other dynamic elements. Here is an example of such a problem:

[image: Imgur link to the screenshot]

As you can see, the list on the left looks garbled. Some buttons like the expand list toggle, search bar (top-right), and seems to have the name of the element overlaid on top of the actual button, making it extremely unreadable.

This happens regardless of whether I'm using Firefox, Chrome or Chromium. I've verified that they are all up-to-date. This doesn't happen in Windows. Could this be a display driver problem? I'm using Nvidia GTX 1060 with the 390 proprietary driver.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ozone!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  I'd agree with your theory.  I checked that website on Chrome here and it looks OK to me.  It could also me memory corruption or a bus error, in my experience.  How does it look if you uninstall the 390 driver?

Comment: @tudor I tried it. The problem is still there with both 390, 396, and the open source one :(